# C1TrueDbGrid / how to find column and row index at point?

Tags: winforms, componentone

I need to handle some behaviour requiring to identify the grid's row and column index for a given point on the screen (like mouse coordinates).

Given a System.Drawing.Point corresponding to mouse coordinates, how can I retrieve the grid's row and column index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in methods, each taking a coordinate.

Example, get the clicked cell in an overridden `MouseDown` event:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 row = RowContaining(e.Y);
    Int32 col = ColContaining(e.X);
}
```

Or, if you have a reference to the grid, the same thought applies:

```
Int32 row = Grid.RowContaining(yCoord);
Int32 col = Grid.ColContaining(xCoord);
```

You can also use the `Point` with ComponentOne's `PointAt` method to identify the clicked region:

```
C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.PointAtEnum ptEnum - Grid.PointAt(e.X, e.Y);
```